# Cannot change NoScript settings

Tags: firefox-extensions, noscript

I've just installed NoScript, and it's now blocking everything (as it should), so when I open YouTube, for example, I cannot watch videos. An alert bar appears at the bottom of the screen: `Scripts currently forbidden | <SCRIPT>: 15 | <OBJECT>: 0` And there's an **Options** button. Clicking the button does nothing. Clicking the NoScript icon in the information bar does nothing. Could some other Firefox extension be interfering? (I have a ridiculous number, some of which I should probably get rid of.)

`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101027 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.12`

Answer (score 0):

The options button isn't where you white/blacklist scripts.

For this it says on the main button menu:

[image: Screenshot of NoScript]

You click on the bottom buttons there, not the options button.

For an easier option, I would use [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/) which instead of blocking everything blocks the trackers and other "bugs", along with [WOT](http://mywot.com), which blocks sites known to have malware.

Comment: Yeah, clicking there got me nowhere either. Nothing happened. I'll try disabling other addons and see if that helps.